# Добавление в бд WEB SQL через JS

Tags: javascript, html, websqldatabase

Нужна помощь. Есть бд через openDatabase, нужно сделать так, чтобы кнопка, например, переносила в таблицу данные из тэгов. Помогите пожалуйста
Вот вырезал пример из кода, хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "В БД" данные из блока шли в таблицу Recipes. То есть "Recipe" это h1, "link"=ссылка из а, "photo"-ссылка на фото, "time"-время из спана, "ingredients"=h6. А при нажатии на кнопку "Из БД" строка удалялась из табл.

```
codepen.io/dduckker/pen/arZMWr
```

Comment: через js можно только запрос дать (если у вас конечно ж сервер не на js).... а так на клиенте даете запрос на сервер и он (сервер) уже работает с БД (удаляет...изменяет...сохраняет и все в таком духе). Запрос либо через `form` либо `ajax`

Comment: то есть без сервера я не смогу это сделать?

Comment: совершенно верно